# Android: Specifying style of programmatically added radio buttons when focused

Tags: android, android-radiobutton

I'm working on my first Android app, and I've run into a bit of a problem concerning the appearance.  I'm programmatically adding radio buttons to a radio group defined in a linear layout.  I'm using a dark theme, and when any of the elements defined in the layout gain focus, they are highlighted in a yellow color: a button with focus has an overall yellow highlight, while a checkbox with focus has yellow text.  But for the dynamically-added radio buttons, when the radio button gains focus the text changes to black (the same as the background).

How do I either specify that the dynamically added radio buttons use the same style on focus as the other elements, or else specify a custom on-focus style for theme?

Here's the code I'm using to add the radio buttons:

```
RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroupVersions);
RadioGroup.LayoutParams rprms;

for(int i=0;i<installedVersionName.size();i++)
{
    RadioButton radioButton = new RadioButton(this);
    radioButton.setText(installedVersionName.get(i));
    radioButton.setId(i);
    rprms = new RadioGroup.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    radioGroup.addView(radioButton, rprms);
}
```

I haven't changed anything about the appearance except setting `android:background="@color/black"` for the LinearLayout to provide a solid background instead of the gradient used by the theme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [TextView.setTextColor(ColorStateList)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setTextColor%28android.content.res.ColorStateList%29) to achieve this.

To create a ColorStateList, just initialize with the different "cases" for the combinations of state flags that you are interested in. For example:

```
ColorStateList colors = new ColorStateList(
    new int[][] {
        new int [] { android.R.attr.state_pressed },
        new int [] { android.R.attr.state_selected },
        new int[0],
    },
    new int[] {
        highlightedColor,
        highlightedColor,
        color,
    });

tv.setTextColor(colors);
```

This would use "color" for the normal state, and "highlightedColor" when the TextView is pressed or selected. For a list of the possible states, see [R.attr](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html). You are probably interested in state_checked but I haven't tested that case.

Comment: Awesome!  That's exactly what I needed.  I'd overlooked that so many widgets inherit from TextView.  For anyone having the same problem, if you have a non-dynamically created element of a similar type, you can get the ColorStateList from that element and apply it to the problem element.  For example, since I had a checkbox defined in the layout, I could do: `CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBoxRemember); radioButton.setTextColor(cb.getTextColors());`